# How to perform nested condition on Array of Object in $lookup Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two documents like below

```js
A = {
    _id: <MongoDb ObjectId>
    user: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    }
    .... <other property>
}

B = {
    _id: <MongoDB ObjectId>
    a: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID
        ref: 'a'
    },
    content: [
        {
            status: {
                c: String
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to Fetch details including b where content can be blank or status.c === 'done' for a user.
A details must content in result, b can be blank if condition not satisfied

I use adapt below method but, unable to get the desired result

```js
A.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {$expr: { $and: [ { user: <SomeDefinedID>} ]}}
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "b",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "a",
            as: 'b'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$b"
    },
    {
        $match: {$expr: { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$b.content.status.c", "done" ] } ]}}
    },
]).exec(console.log);
```

Sometimes I got blank array although I have record in A, b can be [] or the result 'c' as 'done'.